# Creating date counter using javascript in django

Tags: javascript, html, django

For every order, I have a functioning Javascript counter. so when I load the data using a for loop, it should work in each counter for every order. However, only one counter seems to work. What should I change? Here is my code.

The HTML:

```html
    {% for order in orders %}
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 mb-5 justify-content-center wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.1s">
                    <div class="team-item">
                        <div class="team-table position-relative border border-primary rounded p-sm-5 p-5 justify-content-center overflow-hidden">
                            <h5>Application: {{ order.orderdetail }}</h5>
                            <h5 style="color: crimson;">Ordered Time: {{ order.date }}</h5>
                            <h5>Delivery Time: {{ order.delivery_time }}</h5>
                            <div><span style="color: crimson; font-size: large;">Remaining Time: </span><span style="color:crimson;" id="day">0</span><span style="color:crimson;" id="hour">0</span><span style="color:crimson;" id="munite">0</span><span style="color:crimson;" id="second">0</span></span></div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <script>
                    const countDate = new Date('{{order.delivery_time|date:"M-d-y h:m:s"}}').getTime();
                    
                    function delivery_time(){
                        const now = new Date().getTime();
                        let gap = countDate - now;

                        let second = 1000;
                        let munite = second * 60;
                        let hour = munite * 60;
                        let day = hour * 24;

                        let d = Math.floor(gap / (day));
                        let h = Math.floor((gap % (day)) / (hour));
                        let m = Math.floor((gap % (hour)) / (munite));
                        let s = Math.floor((gap % (munite)) / (second));

                        document.getElementById('day').innerText = d + " days ";
                        document.getElementById('hour').innerText = h + " hours ";
                        document.getElementById('munite').innerText = m + " munites ";
                        document.getElementById('second').innerText = s + " seconds ";
                    }

                    
                    setInterval(function(){
                        delivery_time()
                    },1000)
                </script>
                {% endfor %}
```

The orders with counters:
[image: the orders with counters]

Comment: Hello @Ahmet, I advice you to actually upload the code itself and explain what you are trying to achieve more clearly for us to be able to try and help.

Comment: I added codes sorry its very urgent

Comment: Do you have a picture that can help illustrate what is not working?

Comment: @sajeyksmwangi added a picture below the codes. The counter works only in the first order and not in the others.

Comment: Is that the whole HTML code? if not, could you add the whole code?

Comment: @sajeyksmwangiIt  doesn't allow me to add a site right now, causing trouble, but there is nothing to prevent this script above, but there are other javascript libraries below, will it be a problem? And I need to solve this problem urgently, can you help me if I reach you from somewhere?

Comment: What I wanted to see is the whole HTML code for that template, not the site.